# Installing Leopard from DVD: Apple logo?

Tags: macos, install, leopard

I need to install Leopard OSX on my mac.

When the mac starts, I hold the alt button and I load the Leopard Installation DVD. Afterwords I can only see the Apple logo on the screen and everything seems stuck (waited for 8 minutes so far).

How much am I supposed to wait to see the first istructions when loading the Installation DVD at boot time ?

thanks

Comment: Is this the Leopard DVD initially delivered with your Mac? Which Mac model?

Comment: @patrix Yes, delivered with a mac in the office (not sure if it is mine). Mac OS version 10.6.4 - Disc version 4.0

Comment: @Patrick - is your Mac newer than the one the DVD was delivered with?

Comment: @Mark not sure about it, unfortunately :(

Comment: And your Mac is which model/year?

Comment: @patrix iMac12,2 - Intel Core i7

Answer (score 1):

You most probably won't be able to install this OS X version on your iMac:

- 10.6.4 (which is Snow Leopard, not Leopard) was released June 15th, 2010 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Snow_Leopard))
- iMac 12,2 was released mid 2011 ([Apple Support Document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1758))

As a general rule you can't install older OS X discs on newer hardware (missing drivers etc.).